# Issue while uploading CSV file with embedded comma within column

Tags: visualforce, csv, upload, apexinputfile

I am uploading CSV file using `<apex:inputfile>` in vf page. 
CSV file contains 4 columns.

**Scenario 1)** When I try to upload a file without comma in any column, It gets uploaded without any error.

**Scenario 2)** When I try to upload a file with comma present inside column, It gives an error and doesn't get uploaded.

Then I realized that it considers text/data after comma as next column.

How can I avoid or tackle this error.

Below is my function :-

```
public Pagereference ReadFile()
    {
        if(contentFile!=null){
        sourceid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

nameFile= blobToString(contentFile,'ISO 8859-1');
      //  nameFile = contentFile.toString();
        filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
        importupload = new List<ZIS_Quote_Source__c>();
        for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
        {
            String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
            inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

            ZIS_Quote_Source__c a = new ZIS_Quote_Source__c();
            a.Item__c = inputvalues[0];
            String temp1;
            String temps =inputvalues[1].replaceAll('""','@SpaceStation');
            temps  =temps.replaceAll('"','');
            temp1 = temps.replaceAll('@SpaceStation','"');
            IF(temp1.length() >= 250){
                a.Item_Description__c = temp1.substring(0,249);
            }
            else{
                a.Item_Description__c = temp1;
            }    
            a.Full_Description__c = temp1; 
            a.UOM__c = inputvalues[2];
            a.Final_Req__c = Double.valueof(inputvalues[3]);  
            a.Grouping__c = inputvalues[4];
            a.ZISQuote__c = sourceid;
            importupload.add(a);
        }
        }
        try{
        insert importupload;
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Quote Source/s inserted successfully'));
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured. Please check or try again later');
            ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
        }    
        return null;
    }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Tia

Comment: can you post you code ?

Comment: please check. I updated question

Comment: Hi Tia, maybe you can try to save your file as a CSV with ';' as delimiter. Then change your filelines[i].split(',') to filelines[i].split(';').

Comment: Idea is that if the file contains commas inside values, it should be wrapped like "text, some text","12","234". So, that mean that you can not just split the every string, but need to do more complex algorithm -- like go char by char for string, and if there are some doublequote, then comma and then doublequote again -- that's a separator

Comment: Can we import excel file instead of csv file to upload the data?

Comment: I personally use this code sample from Salesforce Technical library. It usually handles all scenarios. [Parsing CSV](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX). I also recommend reading this document which will explain how commas are stored in CSV [Valid CSV rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_valid_record_rows.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully resolved the issue of embedded comma in column.

Here is updated code for future reference :-

```
public Pagereference ReadFile()
{

    if(contentFile!=null){
    sourceid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    nameFile= blobToString(contentFile,'ISO 8859-1');
      //  nameFile = contentFile.toString();
    filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
    importupload = new List<ZIS_Quote_Source__c>();
    for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
    {
        countc = 0;
        String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
        for(Integer j=0; j< filelines[i].length(); j++){
            IF(filelines[i].charAt(j) == 44)
                countc++;
        }
        inputvalues = newSplits = filelines[i].split(',');

        string newval=''; 
        for(integer k=1; k<=countc; k++){
            IF( k==1 || k < (countc-2)){
                 newval = newval + newSplits[k];
            }
        }
        IF(newSplits!= Null){
        inputvalues[0] = newSplits[0];
        inputvalues[1] = newval;
        inputvalues[2] = newSplits[countc-2];
        inputvalues[3] = newSplits[countc-1];
        inputvalues[4] = newSplits[countc];
        }
        ZIS_Quote_Source__c a = new ZIS_Quote_Source__c();
        a.Item__c = inputvalues[0];
        String temp1;
        String temps =inputvalues[1].replaceAll('""','@SpaceStation');
        temps  =temps.replaceAll('"','');
        temp1 = temps.replaceAll('@SpaceStation','"');
        //temp1=inputvalues[1];
        IF(temp1.length() >= 100){
            a.Item_Description__c = temp1.substring(0,100);
        }
        else{
            a.Item_Description__c = temp1;
        }    
        a.Full_Description__c = temp1; 
        a.UOM__c = inputvalues[2];
        a.Final_Req__c = Double.valueof(inputvalues[3]);  
        a.Grouping__c = inputvalues[4];
        a.ZISQuote__c = sourceid;
        importupload.add(a);
    }
    }
    try{
    insert importupload;
    ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Quote Source/s inserted successfully'));
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured. Please check or try again later');
        ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
    }    
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, this is a CSV parser with testmethods that I located from a blog post (which no longer exists) - There could easily be better ways of doing this but it handles embedded commas and double quotes. Code is ca. 2011.  I've used this before

```
public without sharing class CsvReader {
    //  Csv Reader -- courtesy of http://blog.nicocrm.com/2011/03/06/parse-csv-file-in-salesforce-apex/
    //
    //  Usage: Call Constructor with entire Csv Stream then call readLine to get array of string tokens for each line; first row will be header row. readLine returns null at end of stream

    private String      delim = ',';

    private String[]    buffer;                         // the input data for entire CSV file

    private Integer     maxInputLenToAvoidRegex;

    //  ------------------------------
    //  Constructors
    //  ------------------------------
    public CsvReader(String data){
        this.buffer = (data == null ? new List<String>() : data.split('\n'));
    }

    public CsvReader(String data, String delim){
        this.buffer = (data == null ? new List<String>() : data.split('\n'));
        this.delim = delim;
    }

    public CsvReader(String data, Boolean avoidRegexLimit, Integer maxInputLenToAvoidRegex) {
        //  avoidRegexLimit -- apparently, APEX throws an exception on xx.split('\n') when applied to a large file, so, to work around, build the buffer through recursive splitting
        //  reference: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Pattern-and-Matcher-Question/m-p/135986
        this.maxInputLenToAvoidRegex=   maxInputLenToAvoidRegex != null ? maxInputLenToAvoidRegex : 262144;

        if (!avoidRegexLimit)   this.buffer = (data == null ? new List<String>() : data.split('\n'));
        else 
        if (data != null && avoidRegexLimit) {
            Integer pivot           = data.indexOf('\n',Integer.valueOf(Math.floor(data.length() / 2)) );       // determine first split point
            if (pivot > this.maxInputLenToAvoidRegex) {
                this.buffer         = new List<String> ();
                divideStringIntoLines(data);
            }
            else
                this.buffer = data.split('\n');
        }
        else        // null data
            this.buffer = new List<String> ();  
    }

    public String[] getBuffer() {return this.buffer;}

    //  -------------------------------------
    //  divideStringIntoLines (Recursive) - avoids regex too complicated exception on split('\n') when string is large
    //  -------------------------------------
    private void divideStringIntoLines(String inVal) {
        if (inVal == null || inVal.length() == 0) return;
        Integer pivot           = inVal.indexOf('\n',Integer.valueOf(Math.floor(inVal.length() / 2)) );     // determine if inVal is too large
        String  left;           
        String  right;
  /*    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'divideStringIntoLines, inVal=' + inVal + 
                                        '   \npivot ='  + pivot);   */
        if (pivot != -1) {
            left                = inVal.substring(0,pivot);
            right               = inVal.substring(pivot);
/*      System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,
                                        '   \nleft ='   + left +
                                        '   \nright ='  + right); */
            if (pivot < this.maxInputLenToAvoidRegex) {
                List<String>    leftLines   = left.split('\n');
                List<String>    rightLines  = right.split('\n');
                for (String sl: leftLines)
                    if (sl.length() > 0) this.buffer.add(sl);
                for (String sr: rightLines)
                    if (sr.length() > 0) this.buffer.add(sr);
            }
            else {      // recurse as inVal's pivot is bigger than size that regex split can handle
                divideStringIntoLines(left);
                divideStringIntoLines(right);
            }
        }
        else {
            List<String> neitherLeftRightLines = inVal.split('\n');
            for (String s: neitherLeftRightLines)
                if (s.length() > 0) this.buffer.add(s); 
        }   

    }


    //  -------------------------------
    //  readLine - returns array of csv tokens as strings; reads through buffer, removing from buffer as each line is located in toto. Return null if end of stream.
    //  -------------------------------
    public String[] readLine(){
        if(this.buffer.size() == 0) return null;
        String      line        = this.buffer.remove(0);        // grab first part of stream up to newline; remove from buffer
        String[]    parts       = new String[] {};              // result list of tokens for one line
        while(line != ''){
            Integer next = 0;
            if(line.startsWith('"')){
                line = line.substring(1); // strip initial "
                Integer quoteIndex = findQuote(line, 0);        // Look for closing " on same line
                while(quoteIndex == -1){                        //  not found, we must have a newline within a quoted token
                    if(buffer.size() == 0){
                        // EOT!
                        quoteIndex = line.length();
                    } 
                    else {
                        // grab the next line and look to see if closing " can be found
                        Integer skip = line.length();
                        line += '\n' + this.buffer.remove(0);
                        quoteIndex = findQuote(line, skip);
                    }
                }
                // we have a quoted token, advance to comma
                next = quoteIndex + 1;
                parts.add(line.substring(0, quoteIndex).replace('""', '"'));
                } 
            else {      // non-quoted token, token end is at delim
                next = line.indexOf(this.delim, next);
                if(next == -1)
                    next = line.length();
                // NB in Substring, "endindex" is the index of the character AFTER the last index to get
                parts.add(line.substring(0, next));
            }
            if(next == line.length() - 1)
            // case of a terminating comma.
                parts.add('');
            line = next < line.length() ? line.substring(next+1) : '';
        }
        if(parts.size() == 0)
            // empty string - we still want to return something...
            parts.add('');
        return parts;
    }

    static private Pattern quotePattern = Pattern.compile('(?<!")"(?!")');

    //  -------------------------------------------------
    //  Helper: findQuote - find next quote " in line
    private Integer findQuote(String line, Integer skip){
        Matcher m = quotePattern.matcher(line);
        m.region(skip, m.regionEnd());
        if(!m.find())
            return -1;
        return m.start();
    }

    static testmethod void testSplitCsvSimple(){
        String line = 'abc,efg';
        String[] splitted = new CsvReader(line).readLine();
        System.assertEquals(2, splitted.size());

        System.assertEquals('efg', splitted[1]);
        System.assertEquals('abc', splitted[0]);
    }

    static testmethod void testSplitCsvEOL(){
        String line = 'abc,';
        String[] splitted = new CsvReader(line).readLine();
        System.assertEquals(2, splitted.size());

        System.assertEquals('', splitted[1]);
        System.assertEquals('abc', splitted[0]);
    }

    static testmethod void testSplitCsvQuotedSimple(){
        String line = '"abc,def"';
        String[] splitted = new CsvReader(line).readLine();
        System.assertEquals('abc,def', splitted[0]);
    }

    static testmethod void testSplitCsvQuoted(){
        String line = '"abc,def",gh"i,"jk""l",""';
        String[] splitted = new CsvReader(line).readLine();
        System.assertEquals(4, splitted.size());
        System.assertEquals('gh"i', splitted[1]);
        System.assertEquals('abc,def', splitted[0]);
        System.assertEquals('jk"l', splitted[2]);
        System.assertEquals('', splitted[3]);
    }

    static testmethod void testSplitCsvQuotedWithNewLine(){
        String line = '"abc,def\nBoo\nBoo",Test';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line);
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals('abc,def\nBoo\nBoo', splitted[0]);
        System.assertEquals('Test', splitted[1]);
        System.assertEquals(null, reader.readLine());
    }
    static testmethod void testSplitCsvQuotedWithEOT(){
        String line = '"abc,def\nBoo';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line);
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals('abc,def\nBoo', splitted[0]);
        System.assertEquals(null, reader.readLine());
    }

    static testmethod void testTabDelim(){
        String line = 'abc\tdef';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line, '\t');
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals('abc', splitted[0]);
    }
    static testmethod void testSemiColonDelim(){
        String line = 'abc;def;';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line, ';');
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals('abc', splitted[0]);
        System.assertEquals('def', splitted[1]);
    }
    static testmethod void testEmptyStrings(){
        String line = ',,,,';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line);
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals(5, splitted.size());
        for(String s: splitted){
        System.assertEquals('', s);
        }
    }

    // make sure we still get a result even if the source is empty...
    static testmethod void testEmptyString(){
        String line = '';
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(line);
        String[] splitted = reader.readLine();
        System.assertEquals(1, splitted.size());
        System.assertEquals('', splitted[0]);
    }

    //  test that avoidRegexException recursive split works - lines reassembled in correct order, nothing lost

    static testMethod void testAvoidARegex() {

        //  test 00 - simple split with pivot len = 4
        String[]    expRes                      = new List<String> {'00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11'};
        String      line                        = '00\n01\n02\n03\n04\n05\n06\n07\n08\n09\n10\n11';
        CsvReader   reader  = new CsvReader(line,true,4);
        String[]    res     = reader.getBuffer();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'[' + i +'] ' + res[i]);
            System.assertEquals(expRes[i],      res[i]);
        }

        //  test 01 - simple split with pivot len = 3 - to hit the \n       
        reader              = new CsvReader(line,true,3);
        res                 = reader.getBuffer();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'[' + i +'] ' + res[i]); 
            System.assertEquals(expRes[i],      res[i]);
        }

        //  test 02 - simple split with pivot len = 1 - to hit everychar        
        reader              = new CsvReader(line,true,1);
        res                 = reader.getBuffer();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'[' + i +'] ' + res[i]); 
            System.assertEquals(expRes[i],      res[i]);
        }

        //  test 03 - change length of each line
        expRes              = new List<String> {'000','01','002','03','0004','05','000006','07','08','009','10','11'};
        line                        = '000\n01\n002\n03\n0004\n05\n000006\n07\n08\n009\n10\n11';
        reader              = new CsvReader(line,true,5);
        res                 = reader.getBuffer();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'[' + i +'] ' + res[i]); 
            System.assertEquals(expRes[i],      res[i]);
        }

        //  test 04 - use very large pivot > file size  

        reader              = new CsvReader(line,true,null);
        res                 = reader.getBuffer();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'[' + i +'] ' + res[i]); 
            System.assertEquals(expRes[i],      res[i]);
        }
    }



}
```